# Delay in updating the UI in Server application

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

We have been using our blazor for a long time. But still some things about performance are not agreeable.

In the below code, we have sent a JS call that changes the visibility of an element when it returns in a button click, a very small operation.

```
@page "1"
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime;

<div style="width:700px; height:700px; background-color:red">
    <button onclick="@ChangeVisbility">ChangeVisiblity</button>
    <div style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:yellow;visibility:@visiblity;" id="YellowDiv">    </div>
</div>

@code {
    string visiblity = "visible"; 
    public async Task ChangeVisbility()
    {
        bool isVisble = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("CheckVisibility");
        if (isVisble)
        {
            visiblity = "hidden";
        }
        else
        {
            visiblity = "visible";
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: Here there is necessary to send a JS call and get the result to update the Visibility.**

In this, it works very fast in locally. But it's a bit slow when hosting it in Azure or any site.

Hosted link: https://blazorpdfviewerui.azurewebsites.net/

As a blazor developer, we agree it takes some time due to network latency to go to JS and get the result to update the visibility on the C# side. But our customers refuse to recognize this. Because they are all desktop customers. They used fast UI.

Can you give us any tips to increase this performance while hosting?

**Note: We are in the IST region application hosted in the US region.**

**Expected**

1. When i click the button the visibility should update immediately in the hosted environment, even both client and server in different regions as like desktop functionality.

Comment: If you are only manipulating an elements css classes why are you using js?

Comment: How complex (slow) is CheckVisibility() ?

Comment: In Blazor you can use `<div hidden="@(! isVisible)" ... >` but that is probably not the problem.

Comment: @Brian Parker - In my case there there is necessary to send a JS call and get the result position of the element in the above example i have not shown those code.

Comment: @Henk - In my case it gets the bounds of the element and based on the bounds it returns true or false.

Comment: Make sure you have WebSockets enabled and check if you can use a higher serviceplan and/or host in the IST region. Otherwise, use Blazor WebAssembly.

Comment: Hi, its already a year issue, did you found solution for this?